# 54 errors: class, interface, or enum expected error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: android-studio

I'm sure, I'm just missing a brace. But where?

If someone could let me know where I'm missing it, or if it is something else and how to deal with that issue.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rru);
        initialize();
        initializeLogic();

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-4263001851763080~5221870859");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}



    private void initialize(){

        linear1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        linear9=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear9);
        linear2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        linear4=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear4);
        listview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        linear6=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear6);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        linear5=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear5);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        linear7=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear7);
        button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        linear8=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear8);
        button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        _uri_npc=FileUtil.getNewPictureUri(getApplicationContext());
        npc.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,_uri_npc);
        tptsstnocti.setType("image/*");
        tptsstnocti.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        kns=getSharedPreferences("ykt",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        zax=getSharedPreferences("Zax",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tlksd = tlks;
                tlks = tlksd.concat("1");
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tlksd = tlks;
                tlks = tlksd.concat("2");
            }
        });

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tlksd = tlks;
                tlks = tlksd.concat("3");
            }
        });

        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tlksd = tlks;
                tlks = tlksd.concat("4");
            }
        });

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tlksd = tlks;
                tlks = tlksd.concat("5");
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (zax.getString("htbhp", "").equals("")) {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please finish the initial setup");
                }
                else {
                    startActivityForResult(npc, REQ_CD_NPC);
                }
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (zax.getString("htbhp", "").equals("")) {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please finish the initial setup");
                }
                else {
                    startActivityForResult(tptsstnocti, REQ_CD_TPTSSTNOCTI);
                }
            }
        });

        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (zax.getString("htbhp", "").equals("")) {
                    if (tlkt.equals("")) {
                        tlkt = tlks;
                        tlks = "";
                        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please reenter the combo and press exit one more time");
                    }
                    else {
                        if (tlkt.equals(tlks)) {
                            kns.edit().putString("tkun", tlkt).commit();
                            zax.edit().putString("htbhp", "si").commit();
                            listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            linear4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            linear6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "ok everything is setup only thing left is to enjoy piece of mind");
                        }
                        else {
                            tlkt = "";
                            tlks = "";
                            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "combos did not match please try again");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (tlks.equals(kns.getString("tkun", ""))) {
                        listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linear4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linear6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        kil = true;
                        zax.edit().putString("kil", "1").commit();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void initializeLogic() {
        listview1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (zax.getString("htbhp", "").equals("")){
        button3.setAlpha((float)(1));
        button4.setAlpha((float)(1));
        button5.setAlpha((float)(1));
        button6.setAlpha((float)(1));
        button7.setAlpha((float)(1));
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"ok so we've made it to the gallery");
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"but one last precaution all your photos are invisible ");
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"until one last combo is entered again this is the only time the buttons are visible");
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"and there's one more trick up our sleeves ");
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"only with the correct combo entered the exit button will act as the enter button");
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"but will still apear the same");

        ktot = 0;
        while(true){
        if(FileUtil.isExistFile("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(ktot)))))){
        {
        HashMap<String, Object> _item=new HashMap<>();
        _item.put("asd","/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(ktot)))));
        slflu.add((int)ktot,_item);
        }

        ktot++;
        }
        else{
        break;
        }
        }
        listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(slflu));
        ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);

        switch (_requestCode) {
            case REQ_CD_NPC:
            if (_resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 String _filePath = "";
                if (_uri_npc != null) {
                    _filePath = FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _uri_npc);
                }
                pncd = kns.getString("kns", "");
                pnc = Double.parseDouble(pncd.replace("\"", ""));
                FileUtil.moveFile(_filePath, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                {
                    HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
                    _item.put("asd", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                    slflu.add((int)pnc, _item);
                }

                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                pnc++;


                kns.edit().putString("kns", String.valueOf((long)(pnc))).commit();

            }
            else {

            }
            break;

            case REQ_CD_TPTSSTNOCTI:
            if (_resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> _filePath = new ArrayList<>();
                if (_data != null) {
                    if (_data.getClipData() != null) {
                        for (int _index = 0; _index < _data.getClipData().getItemCount(); _index++) {
                            ClipData.Item _item = _data.getClipData().getItemAt(_index);
                            _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _item.getUri()));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _data.getData()));
                    }
                }
                lftits = 0;
                for(int _repeat31 = 0; _repeat31 < (int)(_filePath.size()); _repeat31++) {
                    pnc = Double.parseDouble(kns.getString("kns", ""));
                    FileUtil.moveFile(_filePath.get((int)(lftits)), "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                    {
                        HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
                        _item.put("asd", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                        slflu.add((int)pnc, _item);
                    }

                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.fortblox/files".concat("/sps/".concat(String.valueOf((long)(pnc)))));
                    pnc++;
                    lftits++;
                    kns.edit().putString("kns", String.valueOf((long)(pnc))).commit();
                }


            }
            else {

            }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rru);
        initialize();
        initializeLogic();

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-4263001851763080~5221870859");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}---->this
```

and

```
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (zax.getString("htbhp", "").equals("")) {
                if (tlkt.equals("")) {
                    tlkt = tlks;
                    tlks = "";
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please reenter the combo and press exit one more time");
                }
                else {
                    if (tlkt.equals(tlks)) {
                        kns.edit().putString("tkun", tlkt).commit();
                        zax.edit().putString("htbhp", "si").commit();
                        listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linear4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linear6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "ok everything is setup only thing left is to enjoy piece of mind");
                    }
                    else {
                        tlkt = "";
                        tlks = "";
                        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "combos did not match please try again");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (tlks.equals(kns.getString("tkun", ""))) {
                    listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    linear4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linear6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    kil = true;
                    zax.edit().putString("kil", "1").commit();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });
} ---> this
```

Comment: ok so im left with his now error: ')' expected 
error: illegal start of expression 
error: ';' expected 
error: illegal start of expression 
error: illegal start of expression 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: <identifier> expected 
error: not a statement 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: not a statement 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: illegal start of type